# Running mysql-connector with CMake and C++?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, mysql-connector

I can't seem to find a solution to my CMake problem.

I want to use mysql-connector-c++ and CURL, in my `/Desktop/example` directory I've made the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
PROJECT (main)
ADD_EXECUTABLE (main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main curl mysql-connector-c++)
target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
```

I've included the following headers in my main.cpp:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <driver.h> 
#include <exception.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <statement.h>
```

I've downloaded the [zip file](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/1.1.html) for mysql-connector-c++, unzipped and placed this in my current directory.

I've then run `cmake .` and `make` and the following error is generated:

```
fatal error: 
  'mysql_connection.h' file not found
```

This is bizarre as when I remove the mysql-connector headers, CURL works fine.

Any Idea's as to why this is not working?

N.B 
The following commands run with the stated result:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -lcurl main.cpp  //Success
g++ -std=c++14 -lcurl -lmysqlcppconn main.cpp //Fatal eror: 'mysql_connection.h' file not found
```

Comment: Have you placed the unzipped archive inside `Desktop/example`?

Comment: @fedepad should this be instead of the unzipped `mysql-connector-c++`?

Comment: no need, I'm writing up an answer you could try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that CMake doesn't know about that directory which contains header and library as an "include" or "library" directory. One solution that you can try is to specify the include and link directories before the call

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE (main main.cpp)
```

so your CMakeLists.txt should look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
project(main)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR your_path_to_mysql_connectorcpp)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/cppconn)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main curl mysqlcppconn)
target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
```

Few notes:

1) If you want to call `driver.h` in your sources then you should use the CMakeLists.txt **above**;

2) If you want to call `cppconn/driver.h` in your sources then you should use the CMakeLists.txt **below**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
project(main)
set(FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR your_path_to_mysql_connectorcpp)
include_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/lib)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main curl mysqlcppconn)
target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
```

As your CMake will get more complex, you could also define include directories and libraries on a per target basis, but the above should be ok for the stuff you have now.

Comment: It now states `ld: library not found for -lmysql-connector-c++`

Comment: Are you sure the name of the library is right? As I have downloaded it and the name appears to be `libmysqlcppconn.dylib` so put `mysqlcppconn` instead in  `target_link_libraries() `. I update the answer.

Comment: I'm glad! Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry, I've just tested again and it's now not picking up `<driver.h>`?

Comment: you could try to add that directory too to the include directories, namely add the `${FULL_PATH_TO_MYSQL_CONNECTOR_CPP_DIR}/include/cppconn`. I update the answer.

Comment: wait. Do you call directly <driver.h>?

Comment: Yes, should i provide driver with a path? E.g `<mysql/drive.h>`

Comment: Check the answer, should give both options.

Comment: I think I'm done with the answer, one line in the second fragment was not showing up...

Answer (score 1):

first install mysql library on you mac with

```
brew install mysql-connector-c++
```

and then use the above cmake text

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(connectToMysql)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(connectToMysql main.cpp)
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c++/8.0.25/include)
target_link_libraries(connectToMysql -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c++/8.0.25/lib/)
 target_link_libraries(connectToMysql libmysqlcppconn8.2.8.0.25.dylib)
```

keep in mind that if you want to link a library to cmake
you have to specify the name of that .dylib file

Good luck